# How to create common method for different entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am relatively new to JPA and Hibernate.

I have 7 different non related entities A, B, C,D,E and F. They all extends a common entity called PARENT which had id, created_date and status field.

To mark status field true for all the entities each entity repository (I mean ARepository, BRepository, CRepository, DRepository, ERepository, FRepository) has a method like:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update A set status = :status")
int updateStatus(@Param("status") Boolean status);
```

Calling code is like aRepository.updateStatus(true), bRepository.updateStatus(true), cRepository.updateStatus(true) and so on for all 7 entities ...

I need to stop this calling of each repository and call something like commonrepository.updateStatus(true) where commonrepository is an instance and object could be of each repository (I understand each repository is interface themselves so I am little confused).

Can it be done?

Comment: are these entities in same schema?

Comment: You say they're unrelated but you have a business use case where all 7 repositories need to have the status of their respective entities set to the same value?  Perhaps a data model refactor is in order here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `CommonRepository` with `NoRepositoryBean` annotation, add the `updateStatus` method in this repository

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CommonRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, Serializable> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("update #{#entityName} set status = :status")
    int updateStatus(Boolean status);

    // Other methods
}
```

Make your repositories to extend `CommonRepository`

```
@Repository
public interface ARepository extends CommonRepository<EntityA, Long> {

}

@Repository
public interface BRepository extends CommonRepository<EntityB, Long> {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could make one class that does all the updates and have that class implement all the interfaces programmed to respond with the each different repository.  I don't know exactly if that would help your case or not but it seems like you are making it very tightly coupled and it would help possibly having one class that can do all of them being passed a reference to it.

Comment: Its already tight coupled. I am trying to fix this on the basis of simple java interface concept where a method is overridden in child. Hence, I can create object of child class referencing interface. In such case, I always call interafce.update(); not each class update. Problem in JPA repository is  the repository of entity class are themselves interface.

Answer (score 0):

Set the default value when a object is created. Maybe the default constructor would be the right place to do that. Simply set value in common entity.

```
@Column(name = "STATUS")    
 private boolean status= true;
```

Answer (score 0):

To build off the answer given by UUID, you could then build a wrapper bean that does what you're asking with a bit of spring voodu:

```
@Component
public CommonRepositoryStatusUpdater {
  // spring will inject this list if it finds any; otherwise it is null.
  @Autowired(required = false)
  private List<CommonRepository<?,?>> commonRepositories;

  // updates the status of any detected CommonRepositories.
  public void updateStatus(Boolean value) {
    if ( commonRepositories != null ) {
      commonRepositories.forEach( cr -> cr.updateStatus( value ) );
    }
  }
}
```